# How to write common focus event for all textboxes in application in angular 2 / 4 / 5

Tags: javascript, angular

Im currently written a directive to scrollIntoView for all the textboxes in the application. Adding the directive to thousands of textboxes in the application is painful.

Is there any interceptor kind of thing where i can intercept all focus events of the textbox.

Comment: event delegation (focusin)

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it works.

```
import { Directive, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "[input[type='text']]"
})
export class InputTypeDirective implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('loading directive');
  }

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
  onFocus(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" value="">
```

Also include the directive as declaration in module.